# JQuery collapse, show one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have written a JQuery code to show hide the div. I am not able to just show one at a time. Like if i click on the another div the previous div gets collapsed. I could not fix this out and just spend a day on this. How do i make the previous div collapsed when i click on the new div ?
also, i want to collapse the div itself when i click on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.feature').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(this);


    if ($this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
      $this.removeClass('collapsed');
      $this.find('.feature__description').show(100);
    } else {
      $this.find('.feature__description').hide(100);
      $this.addClass('collapsed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0084cb 0%, #0073b2 100%);
  background-color: #0073b2;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature {
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.feature__title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature--card {
  box-shadow: 0 35px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.feature__icon {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.feature__content {
  width: 100%;
}

.feature__icon img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.feature__description {
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.feature__description::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
}

.feature.collapsed .feature__title::after {
  content: '+';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.feature__title::after {
  content: '-';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Quick and easy way: Just hide all `.feature .feature__description` before you show the clicked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide all of the options before showing your selected option:

```
// Mark all the the features with your collapsed class
$('.feature').addClass('collapsed');
// Hide them all
$('.feature .feature__description').hide(100);
```

Full example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.feature').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
    
      // New code
      $('.feature').addClass('collapsed');
      $('.feature .feature__description').hide(100);
      //
      
      $this.removeClass('collapsed');
      $this.find('.feature__description').show(100);
    } else {
      $this.find('.feature__description').hide(100);
      $this.addClass('collapsed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0084cb 0%, #0073b2 100%);
  background-color: #0073b2;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature {
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.feature__title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature--card {
  box-shadow: 0 35px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.feature__icon {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.feature__content {
  width: 100%;
}

.feature__icon img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.feature__description {
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.feature__description::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
}

.feature.collapsed .feature__title::after {
  content: '+';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.feature__title::after {
  content: '-';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to remove the class from all of them and hide the divs.
that should do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.feature').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(this);

    $('.feature').each(function(){
      $(this).addClass("collapsed");
      $(this).find('.feature__description').hide(100);
    })
    

    if ($this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
      $this.removeClass('collapsed');
      $this.find('.feature__description').show(100);
    } else {
      $this.find('.feature__description').hide(100);
      $this.addClass('collapsed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0084cb 0%, #0073b2 100%);
  background-color: #0073b2;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature {
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.feature__title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature--card {
  box-shadow: 0 35px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.feature__icon {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.feature__content {
  width: 100%;
}

.feature__icon img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.feature__description {
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.feature__description::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  left: 55px;
  top: 15px;
}

.feature.collapsed .feature__title::after {
  content: '+';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.feature__title::after {
  content: '-';
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature feature--card d-flex collapsed">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <div class="feature__title">QuickBooks Integration</div>
      <div class="feature__description">PortPro is integrated with QuickBooks allowing you to better manage invoices and apply all payments. This data automatically flows back into your QuickBooks account.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: you cannot close the collapse anymore